# How to convert IEnumerable to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable

I need to combine several arrays to one. I've found that seems to be a good way to do this:

```
IEnumerable<byte> Combine(byte[] a1, byte[] a2, byte[] a3)
{
    foreach (byte b in a1)
        yield return b;
    foreach (byte b in a2)
        yield return b;
    foreach (byte b in a3)
        yield return b;
}
```

However, I'm not well familiar with `IEnumerable`. How do I convert the result back to `byte[]` so I could work further with it?

Thank you.

Comment: `myEnumerable.ToArray()` ? Or have I misunderstood what you want?

Comment: Any specific reason why you want an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of iterating them just linq's `.Concat`:

```
var joint = a1.Concat(a2).Concat(a3);
```

If you want to return it as an array:

```
joint.ToArray();
```